# What are all of the Pro perks in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In Call Of Duty Black Ops, what are all of the "pro" perks?

For instance, lightweight pro is no falling damage. What are the rest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Source (no longer up): http://www.codblackopsblog.com/call-of-duty-black-ops-perks-list/

### Tier 1

- **Lightweight Pro**: No falling damage.
- **Scavenger Pro**: Doubles your starting ammo with extra magazines and replenishes tactical grenades.
- **Ghost Pro**: Undetectable by aircraft, Infra-red, and Sentries. The enemy won’t see your name or a red crosshair when targeting you.
- **Hardline Pro**: Get a second chance on the result of care packages.
- **Flak Jacket Pro**: Extra fire resistance and reset fuse when you toss back grenades.

### Tier 2

- **Hardened Pro**: Bullets do extra damage to aircraft and Turrets. Reduced flinch when shot at.
- **Scout Pro**: Switch between weapons faster.
- **Steady Aim Pro**: Quicker aiming after sprinting and quicker recovery from knife lunge.
- **Sleight of Hand Pro**: Faster aiming down sights with non-scoped weapons.
- **Warlord Pro**: Start with one extra lethal and tactical grenade (except smoke / Willy Pete)

### Tier 3

- **Marathon Pro**: Unlimited sprint.
- **Ninja Pro**: Louder enemy footsteps, makes you completely silent.
- **Second Chance Pro**: Survive longer and teammates can revive you.
- **Hacker Pro**: Booby trap enemy Care Packages and turn enemy killstreaks and equipment friendly. Makes you invisible to enemy motion sensors.
- **Tactical Mask Pro**: Reduces the effects of flashbangs and concussion grenades. Reveals the location of a flashed or stunned enemy.

Comment: Hacker pro also stops you from showing up on motion sensors.

Comment: In this answer regarding Ghost Pro, does "aircraft" include SR71?