# How do you get the "pro" options for the perks?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

There are a number of challenges related to perks. Do you need to complete them in order to get the "pro" level of that perk ?

Comment: check out http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12630/what-are-all-of-the-pro-perks-in-black-ops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you do, here are the challenges:**

---

> ## Tier 1

---

> **Lightweight** - Move faster
>
> **Lightweight Pro** - Move faster + no fall damage
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Melee Kills - Earn 15 melee kills.
> 2. Escape Death - Escape death 5 times
>      after being hurt.
> 3. Offense Medals - Get 10 Offense
>      Medals by killing enemies near their
>      objective.

---

> **Scavenger** - Replenish ammo and Lethal Grenades from fallen enemies
>
> **Scavenger Pro** - Replenish ammo and Lethal Grenades from fallen enemies +
>   Start with extra mags and replenish
>   Tactical Grenades from fallen enemies
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Resupplies - Resupply 150 times
>      while using Scavenger.
> 2. Grenade Kills - Get 5 Lethal Grenade
>      kills with a resupplied grenade.
> 3. Kill Count - Get 5 kills without
>      dying 5 times.

---

> **Ghost** - Remain hidden from enemy Spy Planes
>
> **Ghost Pro** - Remain hidden from enemy Spy Plans + Avoid targeting from
>   aircraft, IR scopes, and Sentry Guns.
>   No red crosshair or name when
>   targeted.
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Concealed Kills - Kill 20 enemies
>      while they have a Spy Plane or
>      Blackbird active.
> 2. Destroy Aircraft - Destroy 30
>      aircraft with any non-Killstreak
>      launcher.
> 3. Destroy Sentry Gun - Destroy 1
>      Sentry Gun.

---

> **Flak Jacket** - Take less explosive damage
>
> **Flak Jacket Pro** - Take less explosive damage + Deflect fire damage
>   and safely toss back Frag Grenades
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Protected - Survive 10 explosions
>      while using Flack Jacket.
> 2. Demolished - Plant or defuse 10
>      bombs in Demolition, Sabotage, or
>      Search & Destroy.
> 3. Throwbacks - Throw back 5 enemy Frag
>      grenades.

---

> **Hardline** - Earn killstreak rewards with one less kill
>
> **Hardline Pro** - Earn killstreak rewards with one less kill + change
>   the contents of a care package
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Share Packages - Share 10 Killstreak
>      reward crates with teammates.
> 2. Multiple Killstreaks - Earn 7
>      killstreaks in one match while using
>      Hardline.
> 3. Killstreak - Get 7 kills without
>      dying in one match.

---

> ## Tier 2

---

> **Hardened** - Penetrate walls and objects with deeper bullet impact
>
> **Hardened Pro** - Penetrate walls and objects with deeper bullet impact +
>   inflict extra bullet damage on
>   aircraft and turrets, and flinch less
>   when shot
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Penetration Kills - Get 10 kills
>      using Hardened and shooting through
>      walls.
> 2. Bullets in Aircraft - Shoot 200
>      bullets into enemy aircraft.
> 3. Equipment Shot - Destroy 1 piece of
>      enemy equipment through a wall.

---

> **Scout** - Hold breath longer when scoped
>
> **Scout Pro** - Hold breath longer when scoped + switch weapons faster
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Secondary Kills - Get 50 kills with
>      secondary weapons.
> 2. One Shot Kills - Get 50 One Shot,
>      One Kill Medals.
> 3. Headshots - Get 30 Headshot kills.

---

> **Steady Aim** - Maintain increased accuracy when firing from the hip
>
> **Steady Aim Pro** - Maintain increased accuracy when firing from
>   the hip + aim faster after sprinting
>   and recover quickly from knife lunges
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Quick Melee - Melee two enemies
>      consecutively within 5 seconds.
> 2. Sprint Kills - Get 100 kills after
>      sprinting.
> 3. Hip Fire Kills - Get 150 hip fire
>      kills using Steady Aim.

---

> **Sleight of Hand** - Reload weapons faster
>
> **Sleight of Hand Pro** - Reload weapons faster + aim down sights
>   faster with weapons (except Sniper
>   Rifles)
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Aiming Kills - Get 150 kills while
>      aiming down sights.
> 2. Reload Kills - Kill an enemy within
>      5 seconds of reloading 30 times.
> 3. Fast Hand Kills - Reload and finish
>      off the enemy you wounded 10 times.

---

> **Warlord** - Equip two attachments to your primary weapon (excluding
>   underbarrels)
>
> **Warlord Pro** - Equip two attachments to your primary weapon
>   (excluding underbarrels) + start with
>   one extra Tactical and Lethal Grenade
>   (except Willy Pete)
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Two Attachment Kills - Get 150 kills
>      using a gun with two attachments.
> 2. Grenade Kills - Get 10 Frag or
>      Semtex kills.
> 3. Grenade Multi-kills - Get 1
>      multi-kill with Frag or Semtex.

---

> ## Tier 3

---

> **Tactical Mask** - Protect yourself against Nova Gas
>
> **Tactical Mask Pro** - Protect yourself against Nova Gas + reduce the
>   effects of Flash and Concussion
>   Grenades, and reveal the position of a
>   flashed or stunned enemy.
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Flash Kills - Kill 20 enemies that
>      are blinded by your Flashbang.
> 2. Concussion Kills - Kill 20 enemies
>      that are stunned by your Concussion
>      Grenade.
> 3. Nova Gas Kills - Kill 20 enemies
>      poisoned by your Nova Gas.

---

> **Marathon** - Sprint for a longer duration
>
> **Marathon Pro** - Sprint for a longer duration + sprint for an unlimited
>   duration
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. 26 Miles - Sprint 26 miles using
>      Marathon.
> 2. First Blood - Get the First Blood
>      Medal 10 times.
> 3. Captures - In Capture the Flag, get
>      the Flag Capture Medal 15 times
>      while using Marathon.

---

> **Ninja** - Move silently
>
> **Ninja Pro** - Move silently + make no noise at all and hear enemies
>   louder
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Silenced Kills - Get 150 kills using
>      the Suppressor attachment.
> 2. Back Stabs - Get 5 Backstabber
>      Medals.
> 3. Plants - Plant the bomb 10 times in
>      Demolition, Sabotage, or Search &
>      Destroy.

---

> **Second Chance** - Pull out your pistol before dying
>
> **Second Chance Pro** - Pull out your pistol before dying + survive longer
>   and get revived by your teammates
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Kills - Get 10 kills while in Second
>      Chance.
> 2. Revenge - While in Second Chance,
>      kill the enemy who downed you 5
>      times.
> 3. Headshot - Get 1 headshot kill while
>      in Second Chance.

---

> **Hacker** - Detect enemy equipment, explosives and turrets
>
> **Hacker Pro** - Detect enemy equipment, explosives and turrets +
>   sabotage enemy equipment and turrets,
>   booby trap stolen crates and remain
>   invisible to Motion Sensors.
>
> **Challenges**
>
> 1. Destroys - Destroy 10 equipment or
>      explosives while using Hacker.
> 2. Explosive Kills - Kill 25 enemies
>      with a Claymore or C4.
> 3. Near Equipment Kills - Kill 25
>      enemies within the radius of your
>      Jammer or Motion Sensor.

Comment: Very detailed, but you didn't actually answer the question... "Do you need to complete them in order to get the "pro" level of that perk ?"

Comment: @Torpesh  it is pretty obvious from the answer that the challenges I listed need to be completed...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, completing the challenges for each individual perk will unlock its pro level.